# Join multiple queries with different search criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 4 queries that are identical with the exception of one of the criteria clauses at the end.  I am trying to find a way to condense these 4 into 1, if possible.  Currently, a program that we wrote calls these 4 statements through 4 stored procedures, but if I can make that 1 call that returns all 4, that would be great.  Here's the bulk of the statement:

```
SELECT SUM(PausedTime) AS PausedMode
FROM UsageStats
WHERE StartDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @StartDate, 112) AND  StopDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @EndDate, 112)
AND LocationID = @LocationID
AND SystemID = @SystemID
AND PlayingArea = @PlayingArea
AND PausedTime > 0
```

I have 3 more of these and the only thing that changes is the field in the SUM calculation (all SUM fields are of type `int`):

```
SUM(PlayModeTime) AS PlayModeTime
SUM(RecordModeTime) AS RecordModeTime
SUM(ReplayModeTime) AS ReplayModeTime
```

and the last `AND` criteria
    AND PlayModeTime > 0
    AND RecordModeTime > 0
    AND ReplayModeTime > 0

I tried using the `CASE` statement in the select clause but it failed:

```
SELECT
    playMode = (CASE WHEN PlayModeTime > 0 THEN SUM(PlayModeTime) END),
    pausedMode = (CASE WHEN PausedTime > 0 THEN SUM(PausedTime) END),
    recordMode = (CASE WHEN RecordModeTime > 0 THEN SUM(RecordModeTime) END),
    replayMode = (CASE WHEN ReplayModeTime > 0 THEN SUM(ReplayModeTime) END)
FROM UsageStats
WHERE StartDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @StartDate, 112) AND  StopDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @EndDate, 112)
AND LocationID = @LocationID
AND SystemID = @SystemID
AND PlayingArea = @PlayingArea
GROUP BY PlayModeTime, PausedTime, RecordModeTime, ReplayModeTime
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```
PlayModeTime   | PausedMode  | RecordModeTime  | ReplayModeTime
---------------------------------------------------------------
 200              340            10               55
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need those conditions at all, since `SUM` will add zero when the value is `0`. Can't you just `SUM` all of your columns?:

```
SELECT
    playMode = SUM(PlayModeTime),
    pausedMode = SUM(PausedTime),
    recordMode = SUM(RecordModeTime),
    replayMode = SUM(ReplayModeTime)
FROM UsageStats
WHERE StartDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @StartDate, 112) 
AND StopDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @EndDate, 112)
AND LocationID = @LocationID
AND SystemID = @SystemID
AND PlayingArea = @PlayingArea
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the sum outside of the case statement:

```
SELECT
    playMode = SUM(CASE WHEN PlayModeTime > 0 THEN PlayModeTime ELSE 0 END),
    pausedMode = SUM(CASE WHEN PausedTime > 0 THEN PausedTime ELSE 0 END),
    recordMode = SUM(CASE WHEN RecordModeTime > 0 THEN RecordModeTime ELSE 0 END),
    replayMode = SUM(CASE WHEN ReplayModeTime > 0 THEN ReplayModeTime ELSE 0 END)
FROM UsageStats
WHERE StartDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @StartDate, 112) AND  StopDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @EndDate, 112)
AND LocationID = @LocationID
AND SystemID = @SystemID
AND PlayingArea = @PlayingArea
GROUP BY PlayModeTime, PausedTime, RecordModeTime, ReplayModeTime
```

The reason is that the case will be evaluated for each row.  In your example, you're taking the sum of the column, but only for that row.

This only differs from [Lamak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519216/lamak)'s answer above in that it will treat negative values as zeroes in the sum.